# How to add navigation controller to windowbased app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, viewcontroller

I have a window based app. I added two viewcontrollers and one `Tabbarcontroller` to that. Now I want to navigate each viewcontroller to next view. I tried but can't find the solution. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Post up your code and it might be easier to see why things aren't working for you.

Answer (score 2):

When you add the tab bar on window, add like this-

```
NSMutableArray * viewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


FirstViewController * firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController * nvc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstViewController];
[firstViewController release];
[viewControllers addObject:nvc];
[nvc release];

SecondViewController * secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
 nvc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:secondViewController];
[secondViewController release];
[viewControllers addObject:nvc];
[nvc release];

UITabBarController * tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.viewControllers = viewControllers;
[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
```

EDIT - 
Whenever you want to navigate in any one of the controller. All you need is to call

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES];
```

And you will get exactly what you want. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
UINavigationController *urNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootController];
```

If you want to show this on the window

```
[window addSubview:urNavController.view];
```

Answer (score 1):

use like this

```
secondViewController *obj=[[[secondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"secondViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
      UINavigationController *navBar=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:obj];
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:navBar animated:YES];

      [navBar release];
```